# OnEdit Script to Print Executed Formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

So I have a google sheets script that will do on edit of Column 1 to "Print" something in Column 14, And this works. But I'm wanting the print to be a little more dynamic and print what the value of this formula is at the time of the  OnEdit execution (=C1+1) as cell C1 changes weekly. So how do i get this script to "Print" the Results of that formula?

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Current Loads 2020" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 14);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue("Pinted Value");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else looks this up in the future, here's the Answer to my own question.

At first it was executing the script multiple times, but I added the Getrange higher up in the script and that seems to have fixed that issue, and so now it's actually printing the value of the formula =C1+1.

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Current Loads 2020" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var v = s.getRange(1,3).getValue()
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 13);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(v+1);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Current Loads 2020") { 
    if (e.range.columnStart == 1) { 
      var nextCell = e.range.offset(0, 14);
      if (nextCell.getValue() === '') 
        nextCell.setValue(sh.getRange("C1").getValue() + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: this function require the event object to run now

Comment: I don't see at how this does the formula of =C1+1 ???

Comment: It is just getting the value of the edited cell

Comment: when I edit or put in data on column 1, i want this formula to put in the results of C1+1 into Column 14.

Comment: Why  Column C Row 1?  Why not Column C  Row e.range.rowStart?  You stated that you wish it to be dynamic and yet your example  is but incrementing that value of one cell.  I don't understand the point.  Why not set up another section of the onEdit that looks at edits to to this cell?

Comment: This sheet is a Data Sheet, and i'm putting data onto this sheet daily. and each week, the data in cell C1 changes or can change. So right now, i'm having to manually put in the results of C1+1 into it's data spot, which is in Column 14. What i'm wanting is a script that says once i start putting in data, it will automatically look at what the current value of C1 is, and put the results of that formula into column 14 so that i don't have to do it manually.

Comment: And i can't just put in an array formula in column 14, because the value of C1 changes. I need the number that is to be printed in Column 14 to be based on what the value of C1 is at the time of entry and to stay that value forever.

Comment: My on Edit Function works perfect in the fact that it will "Print" the word "Printed Value" into Column 14 once column 1 has been edited. So that part it working, What i need now is help with changing that "Printed Value" text to be the RESULTS of the formula C1+1